# Sampling from a Bivariate Cauchy?

Tags: probability, sampling, bivariate-distributions

Given the bivariate Cauchy distribution:
$$f(x,y; x_0, y_0) \sim \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{((x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2+1)^{1.5}}$$
How do you generate samples appropriately?

I am aware of inverse transforms utilizing the CDF definition, however I can only find articles pertaining to the single variable case.

Thanks!

**Attempt**:

Let $\mathbf{Y}$ be a random vecor of $D$ components

1. Generate $D-1$ random variables $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{D-1}$ of univariate Cauchy distribution via $v_i = \text{tan}(\pi(U - 1/2))$ where $U$ is a uniform on $[0,1]$
2. Generate $w_2, w_3, \dots, w_D$ random variables of a Student t-distribution with $m = 2,3, \dots, D$ degrees of freedom.
3. Set $x_1 = v_1$
4. Iterate the following for $x_m,$ $m = 2,3,\ldots, D$
   $$x_m = m^{-1/2}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}v_i^2\right)^{1/2}w_m$$

So in the bivariate case, $x_1 = v_1$ and 
$$x_2 = 2^{-1/2}\left(1+v_1^2\right)^{1/2}w_2$$

and $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X} + \mathbf{Y}_{\text{curr}}$ since the given scale parameter is 1?

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

A multivariate Cauchy distribution coincides with a multivariate Student's t distribution with 1 degree of freedom. You can generate the Student's t distribution samples via Normals with standard sample-generating theory and Cholesky.
Stay safe

Comment: what is the correlation matrix of a bivariate Cauchy? Wouldn't you need that to generate a multivariate Student's t distribution?